# Android device not able to connect to localhost

Tags: php, android, mysql

I developed an android app .. in which data is saved in mysql and php files are used as webservice.. My android app works fine in emulator .. and when i checked with the real device it WAS not working ... when i turned the firewall off ( Windows OS ) it is now working fine in my android device.. also .. so what I have to do it working with Windows firewall in turn on position..

I used [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/) tuorial for developing app

Comment: http://iascpl.com/app/get_all_products.php

Answer (score 0):

Please you write your ip address is your url

e.g- `private static String mainurl = "http://192.168.0.11/yourphpfilename.php";`

Comment: that all  working fine... I gave my ip  http://10.208.198.1/android_connect/get_product_details.php    like this but it is working in android device only when systems windows firewall is turned off... otherwise it is working fine in emulator